# How do I use a component in a vue route?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to use a vue component `<channel-card></channel-card>` in my home route and I'm running into a host of errors.

**main.js**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {path: '/home', component: home}
  ],
  mode: 'history'
});
```

**home.vue route**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <main class=" bg-white w-full h-100vh shadow-md p-2">
      <channel-card></channel-card>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Error**

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <channel-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Home> at src/components/home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
        <Root>
```

**ChannelCard.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'ChannelCard',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I've also tried adding this to my home.vue route:

```
import ChannelCard from './partials/ChannelCard.vue';
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: { ChannelCard },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> ./partials/ChannelCard.vue in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/b
>   abel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vu
>   e-loader-options!./src/components/home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the `<channel-card>` component and add it to `components` in the script section of `home.vue`:

home.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <main class=" bg-white w-full h-100vh shadow-md p-2">
      <channel-card></channel-card>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import channelCard from './channel-card.vue';

export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: { channelCard },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I had tried that and got this error:

>This relative module was not found:

* ./components/views/partials/ChannelCard in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./n
ode_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-l
oader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Comment: I'm totally sorry, I just edited your post instead of mine.

Comment: @user3325126 Is there a component `ChannelCard.vue` in the folder `./components/views/partials`?